# acts_as_list with paranoia gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list, acts-as-paranoid

I have two models. The first ModelA is the parent of ModelB. ie ModelA has_many ModelB. [When modelA is destroyed, all its dependent ModelB's also gets destroyed due to dependent destroy 
Now I have acts_as_paranoid scope: :ModelA

With this,I also have acts_as_paranoid set up for both Models A&B.

Now when I am destroying ModelA, I don't wan't the callbacks in ModelB to be called when ModelB records gets destroyed.

Particularly, ModelB has something called as position as an attribute, which gets updated when ModelA gets paranoia destroyed which causes the position attribute of ModelB to change.
I wan't the position not to change so that I can safely restore the ModelA  with the same records and properties for ModelB which was there before.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your model callback?

Comment: The callback is being called implicitly by acts_as_list whenever destroy is called on modelB.
https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb Here the function 'decrement_positions_on_higher_items' gets called implicitly, which decrements all the subsequent modelB records's position by 1

Comment: This should come handy `disabling temporarily` https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/README.md#disabling-temporarily

Comment: Have you investigated making ModelB paranoid also? That should bypass its normal destroy procedures? I'm not 100% sure, but I thought that's how it should work. In my application I don't use any of those gems for that function. I just have a few methods that I call to 'trash' and 'restore' an item, then the destroy functionality never gets called. You can then use scopes to hide these 'trashed' records by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [readme](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/README.md#disabling-temporarily)

```
ModelB.acts_as_list_no_update do
  modela_instance.destroy
end
```

This should work. I wish I could test it, unfortunately don't have such setup. Let me know if any issues.
Hope it helps..

---

Update: syntax that worked for this case as in comments.

```
ModelB.acts_as_list_no_update([ModelB]) do
  modela_instance.destroy
end
```

Comment: Hi Farhan, That worked actually with minor changes. I had to update the acts_as_list to latest version.
 ModleB.acts_as_list_no_update [ModelB] {}

Comment: @AdilHussain I would appreciate an upvote and/or accept answer since it worked.

Comment: @Farhan, Sorry I just forgot that. Thanks for your answer. :)